# How can I fix this issue inside my cards that are loaded when the title is long

Tags: css

[here is my loaded cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DX9W.jpg)

[here is a picture of the css i have for the cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKk7F.png)

[image: here is the html]

I have tried word-wrap and overflow but nothing seems to make any difference. I am open to any suggestions on how to fix this problem.

[image: here is my generated html]

Comment: Provide a minimal code example here.

Comment: You can edit your question and post the written code.

Comment: Sorry first time posting here I am trying to give all the information that is needed

Comment: @briancrisp could you show us the finished html code (which will be generated by your js method) of your card? This would be extremly helpful^^

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for this on card-title add these css proerties to yoou card title

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian, next time plz share your code in text form not in image form! thanks.
To Wrap text you have to set overflow to hidden for parent.

```
<html>
   <!-- Code just for reference -->
   <body style="display: flex;">
     <div style="overflow: hidden;background: red;">
        <h5 style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">Hello world this is text that will wrap</h5>
     </div>
    <!-- increase width of second div and first div's text will wrap when it get conjested -->
    <div style="width: 900px;overflow: hidden;background: blue;">
        <h5>Hello world this is text blah blah</h5>
    </div>
   </body>
</html>`
```

In your case set "overflow: hidden" for 'card' class and for 'card-title' class title set these three properties

```
{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try and I will share my code in text next time. I thought the pictures would be a better idea. Thank you

Comment: This did not resolve the issue Nothing changed at all.

Comment: For this solution to work, parent('card' class) must have a specific width or when its width decreases to extent where its text overflows, check this [pen](https://codepen.io/abu-bakar-1972/pen/YzQYmyq)

Comment: Thank you Abu Bakar your comment got me playing with it and it turns out all i had to do was set a width on the main card i did not need any of the other style suggestions. Thank you everyone for you're input..

Comment: @briancrisp No problem. If this is solution to your question than accept it as an answer !Thanks.